# How can I ensure that disabled logging calls are optimized out at compile-time, even on debug builds?

Tags: c++, logging, macros

I want to write a C++ logging class for an embedded device.
What is very important, that log instructions that are not "activated" are optimized out by the preprocessor !

Until now, I did something like that:

```
#define LOGLEVEL 3

#if LOGLEVEL > 3
#define LOG_DEBUG(...) Serial.printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define LOG_DEBUG()
#endif

#if LOGLEVEL > 2
#define LOG_INFO(...) Serial.printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define LOG_INFO()
#endif

LOG_DEBUG("var a is: &d", a); // will be completely optimized out
LOG_INFO("var b is: %f", b);
```

Now I want to be a bit more sophisticated with a more tunable output:

```
#define LOGLEVEL 5
#define LOGAREAS LOGAREA_THIS | LOGAREAS_THAT

#define LOGAREA_THIS 0x01
#define LOGAREA_THAT 0x02
#define LOGAREA_FOO 0x04
#define LOGAREA_BAR 0x08


#if LOGLEVEL > 4
#define LOG_TRACE(x, ...) if(x & LOGAREAS) Serial.printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define LOG_TRACE()
#endif

LOG_TRACE(LOGAREA_THIS, "var b is: %f", b);
LOG_TRACE(LOGAREA_FOO | LOGAREA_BAR , "var a is: &d", a); // only displayed if LOGAREA_FOO or LOGAREA_BAR is selected
```

problem is with that code, that unselected messages still are in the cpp code and with no optimization (for debuging) still find their way into my binary...

Is there a way with a similar usability that allows me to do what I want where the unused messages are removed completely?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for macros here.

```
constexpr auto LOGAREA_THIS = 0x01;
constexpr auto LOGAREA_THAT = 0x02;
constexpr auto LOGAREA_FOO = 0x04;
constexpr auto LOGAREA_BAR = 0x08;

constexpr auto LOGLEVEL = 5;
constexpr auto LOGAREAS = LOGAREA_THIS | LOGAREAS_THAT;

template<auto x, typename... Args>
constexpr void LOG_TRACE(Args&&... args) {
    if constexpr((LOGLEVEL > 4) && (x & LOGAREAS))
        Serial.printf(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

//...

LOG_TRACE<LOGAREA_THIS>("var b is: %f", b);
LOG_TRACE<LOGAREA_FOO | LOGAREA_BAR>("var a is: &d", a);
```

It may be possible that the compiler doesn't inline the call to `LOG_TRACE` in some cases, e.g. if in `-O0` builds and if `LOG_TRACE` is called multiple times with the same log flags and argument types. In that case it would help to add some compiler-specific `[[gnu:always_inline]]` or `__forceinline` type attribute to `LOG_TRACE`.

Comment: You should probably forceinline this, since OP wants disabled calls to compile to nothing even in debug builds. (I hope this works.)

Comment: Alternatively, you could have a macro `LOG_TRACE(level, ...)` that expands to something like `__builtin_choose_expr(check level, log(__VA_ARGS__), void())`. That would guarantee no code being emitted even on debug builds.

Comment: constexpr looks promissing, I'll gvae it a try. The auto param seems to be only supported since c++20, which is a bit new for an embeded, multi-plattform lib.
But changing this to uint64_t fixes this issue.

@JanSchultke __builtin_choose_expr is only availible for C, not C++.

Comment: @SirSydom `auto` template parameters are available since C++17 and the other `auto` have been available since C++11. Yes, you can of course choose the type explicitly. (In an earlier revision of the answer I used `auto` function parameters, i.e. so-called "abbreviated templates", but that was a mistake. They are only available in C++20.) C++17 is also required for `if constexpr`, which is fundamentally the important part of the answer. Just `if` won't work as intended.

Comment: I got this compiler message while using
arm-none-eabi-gcc (15:9-2019-q4-0ubuntu1) 9.2.1 20191025 (release) [ARM/arm-9-branch revision 277599]

```
/home/runner/work/knx/knx/src/knx/logger.h: At global scope:
/home/runner/work/knx/knx/src/knx/logger.h:59:15: error: parameter declared 'auto'
   59 | template<auto x, typename... Args>
      |               ^
```

Comment: @SirSydom You need to compile with `-std=c++17` (or `-std=gnu++17`). It should be complaining about `if constexpr` as well if you are not compiling in C++17 mode (although GCC with default options downgrades this to a warning).

Answer (score 0):

If you change your syntax to something like this:

```cpp
LOG_TRACE(LOGAREA_FOO, LOGAREA_BAR)("var a is: %d", a);
```

(Changing your bitwise `|` into a comma and having a second pair of brackets), you can make things like `LOG_TRACE(0, 0, 0, 0)` (all zeroes) expand into a macro that ignores its arguments and if there are any ones it expands into a macro that calls the log function with its arguments.

This means instead of a bitmask, all of your `LOGAREA_*` macros are either zero or one.

With Boost.Preprocessor, you can build a macro that does this:

```cpp
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#define ANY_OF_OP(S, STATE, X) BOOST_PP_BITOR(STATE, X)
#define ANY_OF(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOLD_LEFT(ANY_OF_OP, 0, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))

#define LOGGER(...) static_cast<void>(std::printf(__VA_ARGS__))
#define NOLOGGER(...) static_cast<void>(0)
#define LOG(MINIMUM_LEVEL, ...) BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_BITAND(BOOST_PP_GREATER_EQUAL(LOGLEVEL, MINIMUM_LEVEL), ANY_OF(__VA_ARGS__)), LOGGER, NOLOGGER)

#define LOG_TRACE(...) LOG(5, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_DEBUG(...) LOG(4, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG_INFO(...) LOG(3, __VA_ARGS__)


// Configuration
#define LOGLEVEL 5
#define LOGAREA_THIS 1
#define LOGAREA_THAT 1
#define LOGAREA_FOO 0
#define LOGAREA_BAR 0
```

```cpp
// Example usage
int a;
float b;

int main() {
    LOG_TRACE(LOGAREA_THIS)("var b is: %f", b);
    LOG_TRACE(LOGAREA_FOO, LOGAREA_BAR)("var a is: %d", a);
    // With above configuration, this expands to
    static_cast<void>(Serial.printf("var b is: %f", b));
    static_cast<void>(0);
}
```

With a bit of grunt work this can be done without Boost.Preprocessor too: https://godbolt.org/z/bG6Mdxves

Comment: this is a very nice approach, I like it.
But the dependency to boost is problematic..
I give the "grunt" version a try :)